# R - handle error when accessing a database

Tags: r, database, error-handling, rjdbc

I'm trying to automate data download from db using `RJDBC` using a for loop. The database im using automatically closes the connection after every 10mins, so what i want to do is somehow catch the error, remake the connection, and continue the loop. In order to do this i need to capture the error somehow, the problem is, it is not an r error so none of the commands `trycatch` and similar works. I just get a text on the console telling me:

`Error in .jcheck() : No running JVM detected. Maybe .jinit() would help.`

How do i handle this in terms of:

`if (output == ERROR) {remake connection and run dbQuery} else {run dbQuery}`

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `pool` package [to abstract away the logic of connection management](https://db.rstudio.com/pool/).
This does exactly what you expect regarding connection management with `DBI`.
It should work with `RJDBC`  [which is an implentation of DBI](https://rdrr.io/cran/RJDBC/), but I didn't test it with this driver.

```
libray(pool)
library(RJDBC)

conn <- dbPool(
  drv = RJDBC::JDBC(...),
  dbname = "mydb",
  host = "hostadress",
  username = "test",
  password = "test"
)
on.exit(poolClose(conn))

dbGetQuery(conn, "select... ")
```

Comment: the problem is, the connection closes automatically. What i want to do is to check if it is closes while my loop is ongoing

Comment: If the connection closes, `pool` will reopen it as soon as you query again the database. Does the connection close while a query in running?

Comment: it usually closes while the for loop is running, so i need to remake it if its closed

Comment: To help further, I would need some more detail on the way the loop is working : could you provide a code example? `pool` will reopen automatically a closed connection. Did you try?